# How to store all links into a text file?

Tags: org-mode

I have stored some links using `org-store-link`. I want to write a function which when called, would print all of them into an org file. Something like this:

```
(defun write-to-file()
 (interactive)
 (setq filename "test.org")
 (append-to-file   (org-insert-all-links 1)  nil filename))
```

How to make the above work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `org-insert-all-links` does not return a string with the links but writes the links to the current buffer.
You get a solution that is closest to what you already have if you create a temporary buffer with `with-temp-buffer` let `org-insert-all-links` put the links there and request the buffer string with `buffer-string`.

```el
(defun write-to-file()
 (interactive)
 (setq filename "test.org")
 (append-to-file
  (with-temp-buffer
    (org-insert-all-links 1)
    (buffer-string))
  nil filename))
```

Nevertheless I would suggest to open a buffer with buffer file `test.org` and just write the links at the end of that file.

```el
(defun write-to-file ()
  "Write all stored links into file test.org."
  (interactive)
  (setq filename "test.org")
  (let ((already-open (get-file-buffer filename)))
    (with-current-buffer (or already-open (find-file-noselect filename))
      (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (org-insert-all-links 1))
      (save-buffer 0)
      (unless already-open
        (kill-buffer)))))
```